# Ajax crawling : snapshot page dissimilar with user page

Tags: seo, ajax, web-crawlers

For ajax-crawling purpose I make snapshots pages. My problem is user view pages and snapshot pages are dissimilar (tags `h1`, `h2`...).

Example:

- user view page: `http://www.meomap.net/#!/place/1`
- snapshots page: `http://www.meomap.net/?_escaped_fragment_=/place/1`

My question is that it is bad or no problem for SEO?

Comment: Sorry but what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question

Comment: Sorry, but how can I get your snapshots page? I have tried to find it on your site, but I didn't find it.

Comment: try [link](http://www.meomap.net/?_escaped_fragment_=/place/1) is a snapshot page

Comment: I have found it here, but how can user reach this url on your website?

Comment: user not used this url, is desing for bot crawl, for example user view [http://www.meomap.net/#!/place/1](http://www.meomap.net/#!/place/1) and for bot [http://www.meomap.net/?_escaped_fragment_=/place/1](http://www.meomap.net/?_escaped_fragment_=/place/1) both links are the same content

Answer (score 1):

I have found some related article:
1. http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html
2. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/27/searchable-dynamic-content-with-ajax-crawling/

And :
"...AJAX-crawling applications always show different results to Google than to regular browsers, but it isn’t cloaking if the HTML snippets contain the same content that the user would see in the browser."